# Why $|f|=1$ on the boundary?

Tags: complex-analysis

The function $f(z)=\exp(\exp(z))$ on the domain $U=\{z=x+iy:-\pi/2<y<\pi/2\}$. Why $|f|=1$ on the boundary of $U$?

$$
|f(x\pm i\pi/2)|=\left|\exp(\exp(x\pm i\pi/2))\right|
$$
I don't know why it is 1?

Based on Harald's hint, I want to prove $e^{x\pm i\pi/2}$ is imaginary.
$$
e^{x\pm i\pi/2}=e^x[\cos(\pi/2)\pm i\sin(\pi/2)]=\pm ie^x.
$$

Comment: If $x$ is real then $x+\pi/2$ is not on the boundary.

Comment: There was an obvious misprint in the question (missing $i$ in some places). I fixed that, and also replaced $+$ by $\pm$ to accomodate both components of the boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $\lvert e^w\rvert=1$ if and only if $w$ is imaginary. It follows that you need to show that $\exp(x\pm i\pi/2)$ is imaginary for any real $x$. As this smells a bit like homework, I am going to let you finish it on your own.

Comment: Thank you, Harald, I got it. You hint is very helpful.

Comment: @Harald  : The smell of homework... it stinks, doesn't it? :P

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: I would choose kinder words. We were all beginners once.

Comment: @Harald : Oh, it could've sounded mean, but I assure you it was just a joke. More like "Don't we all hate homework in general?" than "Don't we hate MSE people asking for homework?"